# swift - display items in table view by category / tag?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, categories

Im building a swift app and need some help with two problems. I'm fairly new to swift and coding in general. My app saves a bunch of items into an array, and currently the tableview on the home screen displays them. but i'd like to take it a step further and would like to be able to categorize the items. for example, a shopping list. You could save "bananas", "pasta", "apples", "bread", "strawberries", and "Milk" as items into the array.

1. How could I associate a tag to each item? Say, tag bananas, apples, and strawberries as "fruit" and save that item to the array.

and

2. How could I display just items with the "fruit" tag in a tableview? Lets say the home screen is a list of all items, but you select the tag, and it then just displays items with the "fruit" tag...etc.

this is just a simple example to help illustrate my point, but I'd like to know how to work with my data like this.

If anyone has any ideas or any resources to point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: From the top of my head, I'd say each item should be some sort of struct with a name (String) and an itemType (an enum). Then you could filter the array on itemType.

Comment: thanks @nickfalk. that gives me enough info to dig around a little further. i found this reference that i think will be able to help explain it further. instead of categorizing food, its categorizing contacts, but the principle is the same. thanks for the help!

Comment: link: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/enums-structs-swift

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. To associate some things with another in Swift (and in almost all programming languages) you should use [`Dictionaries`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113). How to implement it in your case? Well, very simple. First, i suggest you to create [`enum`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH12-ID145) to store you food types or whatever:

   ```
   enum FoodType {
       case Fruits, Vegetables
   }
   ```

   Now, create your food repository, where you store food (or `value`) and associate its with some tag (or `key`):

   ```
   var myFood = [FoodType : [String]]()
   ```

   Now you can add you food to your `myFood` variable like this:

   ```
   food[.Fruits] = ["Bananas", "Apples", "Strawberries"]
   food[.Vegetables] = ["Potato", "Carrot"]
   ```
2. To select *fruits* do this:

   ```
   var onlyFruits = food[.Fruits]
   ```

   Now, `onlyFruits` contains only food that tagged by `.Fruits`.